# Consumer: Send offset again if middleware lost connection to external appilication

Tags: apache-kafka, spring-cloud-stream

Im new to spring cloud stream and kafka in general.

What is the best approach to stop the Consumer committing to the next offset if the external application doesn't get the last message. I have a middleware that manages communication between the consumer and the external application. I want to, at least, try to send the message 10 times with a 1 minute delay between (to the external application) if something goes wrong.

The Middleware is a simple post request application that filters for specific data in the kafka message.

Comment: Hello @Lomo Gen and welcome to StackOverflow. Please try to be more specific in your question (ie. what is 'a middleware' in your case). Try to add some code to show what you have tried and did not work.

Answer (score 0):

If the exception is thrown, the binder will try 3 times by default and then throw the exception the kafka listener container.

You can use a `ListenerContainerCustomizer` bean to [customize the listener container](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/spring-cloud-stream/2.2.1.RELEASE/spring-cloud-stream.html#_advanced_consumer_configuration) to add a `SeekToCurrentErrorHandler`.

See the [spring-kafka documentation about stateful retry](https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/2.2.10.RELEASE/reference/html/#stateful-retry).